# Leaked IntentReceiver Exception using osmdroid

Tags: java, android, exception, osmdroid

I have in my Android app a MapActivity, that shows map using osmdroid (Open Street Map for Android library).

When I'm in this MapActivity and I go to another activity, I get always an exception, and I cannot understand how to avoid it, because I think that it is related to something done inside the library.
As you can see in the following log, it happen after destroying of MapActivity

```
05-18 17:34:31.117  27073-27073/com.fpricoco.etip I/﹕ Classe 'MapActivity'  ----  'onDestroy()'  ----  Stato: Distrutta
05-18 17:34:31.157  27073-27073/com.fpricoco.etip E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.fpricoco.etip.Activities.MapActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase$MyBroadcastReceiver@43d85f60 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.fpricoco.etip.Activities.MapActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase$MyBroadcastReceiver@43d85f60 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1151)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1138)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1132)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:365)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.util.SimpleRegisterReceiver.registerReceiver(SimpleRegisterReceiver.java:21)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase.<init>(MapTileFileStorageProviderBase.java:34)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileArchiveProvider.<init>(MapTileFileArchiveProvider.java:57)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileArchiveProvider.<init>(MapTileFileArchiveProvider.java:76)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:63)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:41)
            at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBasic.<init>(MapTileProviderBasic.java:34)
            at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MinimapOverlay.<init>(MinimapOverlay.java:114)
            at com.fpricoco.etip.Activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:303)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4791)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Searching on Google I found that I have to "unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver)", the point is that I don't have in my case any "yourReceiver" setted in my code, I think it is done inside library.

I also found this solution "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmdroid/wDEvFpWfTIU"  , but I don't understand how to detach

Finally I also tried in this way, but it didn't work:

```
// .. get custom tiles off the screen
myMapView.getOverlays().remove(mMinimapOverlay);
// .. release all custom tiles' bitmaps
myMapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();
// .. unregister intent receiver
myMapView.getTileProvider().detach();
```

The library I imported is:

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.1@aar'
```

inside my gradle.build file.

Comment: "yourReceiver" is an example name for an receiver parameter. It is normal you couldn't find the variable yourReceiver. Try looking in your code what could be accepted in the unregisterReceiver() call.

Comment: Also, reading from your log, it hints you the problem is near line 303 as hinted here `at com.fpricoco.etip.Activities.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:303)`.

Comment: Hi, of course I know that "yourReceiver" is an example", but unregisterReceiver()  wants as argument an object of type BroadcastReceiver;  the point is that I don't have any object of this type in my code.
In line 303 I have:
            mMinimapOverlay = new MinimapOverlay(myContext, myMapView.getTileRequestCompleteHandler());

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
myMapView.onDetach();
myMapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();
}
```